# Mac OS X roaming profile from Samba with OpenLDAP backend on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: samba, openldap

I have been battling for a week now to get my Mac (Mountain Lion) to authenticate on my home network's OpenLDAP and Samba.  From several sources, like the Ubuntu community docs, and other blogs, and after a hell of a lot of trial and error and piecing things together, I have created a samba.ldif that will pass the smbldap-populate when combined with apple.ldif and I have a fully functional OpenLDAP server and a Samba PDC that uses LDAP to authenticate the OS X Machine.

The problem is that when I login, the home directory is not created or pulled from the server.  I get the following in system.log

```
Sep 21 06:09:15 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local SecurityAgent[265]: User info context values set for sam
Sep 21 06:09:15 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local authorizationhost[270]: in pam_sm_authenticate():   Got user: sam
Sep 21 06:09:15 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local authorizationhost[270]: in pam_sm_authenticate():     Got ruser: (null)
Sep 21 06:09:15 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local authorizationhost[270]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Got service: authorization
Sep 21 06:09:15 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local authorizationhost[270]: in od_principal_for_user(): no authauth availale for user.
Sep 21 06:09:15 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local authorizationhost[270]: in od_principal_for_user(): failed: 7
Sep 21 06:09:15 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local authorizationhost[270]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Failed to determine Kerberos principal name.
Sep 21 06:09:15 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local authorizationhost[270]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Done cleanup3
Sep 21 06:09:15 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local authorizationhost[270]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): Kerberos 5 refuses you
Sep 21 06:09:15 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local authorizationhost[270]: in pam_sm_authenticate(): pam_sm_authenticate: ntlm
Sep 21 06:09:15 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local authorizationhost[270]: in pam_sm_acct_mgmt(): OpenDirectory - Membership cache TTL set to 1800.
Sep 21 06:09:15 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local authorizationhost[270]: in od_record_check_pwpolicy(): retval: 0
Sep 21 06:09:15 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local authorizationhost[270]: in pam_sm_setcred(): Establishing credentials
Sep 21 06:09:15 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local authorizationhost[270]: in pam_sm_setcred(): Got user: sam
Sep 21 06:09:15 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local authorizationhost[270]: in pam_sm_setcred(): Context initialised
Sep 21 06:09:15 Sams-MacBook-Pro.local authorizationhost[270]: in pam_sm_setcred(): pam_sm_setcred: ntlm user sam doesn't have auth authority
```

All that's great and good and I authenticate.  Then I get

```
CFPreferences: user home directory for user kCFPreferencesCurrentUser at
/Network/Servers/172.17.148.186/home/sam is unavailable. 
User domains will be volatile.

Failed looking up user domain root; url='file://localhost/Network/Servers/172.17.148.186/home/sam/'
path=/Network/Servers/172.17.148.186/home/sam/ err=-43 uid=9000 euid=9000
```

If you're wondering where **/Network/Servers/IP/home/sam** comes from, it's from a couple of blogs that said the OpenLDAP attribute **apple-user-homeDirectory** should have that value and the **NFSHomeDirectory** on the mac should point to **apple-user-homeDirectory**

I also set the attr **apple-user-homeurl** to

```
<home_dir><url>smb://172.17.148.186/sam/</url><path></path></home_dir>
```

which I found on this forum.

Any help is appreciated, because I'm banging my head against the wall at this point.

By the way, I intend to create a blog on my vps just for this, and create an install script in python that people can download so no one has to go through what I've had to go through this week :)

After some sleep I am going to try to login from a windows machine and report back here.

Thanks

Sam

Comment: I am also pretty sure that since Lion **/Network/Servers** is not used anymore to bind shared connected computers, so where should that path point to

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the problem.

It was a stupid typo!

Instead of **/Network/Servers** it should be **/Network/Server**.  That stupid extra **S** kept me in circles for days!

Now I want to mount the home directory as an nfs mount, so that all my data is on the server.